# Weird behavior for user connections

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

we're noticing the following behavior for the user connections perfmonce counter under SQL Server -> general statistics. connections appear to be closed or recycled every 30 seconds.
 our server is very busy (high CPU). Is this a normal behavior?

You can check the image for the connections performance counter SQL Server here: http://www.fotoshack.us/fotos/77434conn.gif

Comment: Have you used any profiling tool on you code to find out whats causing it

Comment: may be you are not closing your connections in your .net application and sql server is being forced to do so once its reaching the limit.. guessing here..

Comment: We've used sql profiler and we see sp_reset_connection calls. Are there any other things we can look into? Is there a way to know whether SQL or .Net is closing the connections? thanks

Comment: @Baz1nga well we increased the app pool size to 4000 connections and can have up to 1000 users online concurrently

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your ASP.NET application might be having a sqlconnection not closed properly or just sql stored proc written poorly

To find out what is causing this in your asp.net or atleast get close to the code that is poor I would suggest you use use something like [JetBrains Dot Trace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) or [Red gates Ants Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=unmet_need&utm_campaign=antsmemoryprofiler&gclid=COrg4qfOrbECFYwhtAod1QQAVw)

There are more in the market but perosanlly I would suggest Jet Brains dot Trace it has saved my neck few times

Comment: how does dotTrace help you in identifying active database connections??

Comment: @Baz1nga dotTrace 5 quickly find performance bottlenecks, you can profile you asp.net application with it page by page, it shows you the hotspot means a particular code have take N% out of total 100%.

Comment: OK we will try out JetBrains Dot Trace tomorrow and see what can we find out. Thanks

Comment: I know what the tool does! doesnt mean it will show you what is the cause of the bottleneck always.. something like 10000 connectins being active all from different threads cannot be traced by dotTrace